# Strange Ivy Error Message

Tags: ant, ivy

I'm using ant with maven to build a multi module project. Until now everything worked fine but now ivy complains that it finds a"bad module".

```
java.text.ParseException: inconsistent module descriptor file found 
in 'XYZ.ivy.xml': bad module found in XYZ.ivy.xml: expected='true' found='null';
```

I don't know what ivy want's to tell me with this message, maybe somone else can?
The ivy xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">

    <info organisation="xyz" module="ebusiness-core" revision="1.0" status="integration" publication="20100104174318" e:package="jar"/>

    <configurations>
                <conf name="default" visibility="public" extends="runtime,master"/>
                <conf name="master" visibility="public" />
                <conf name="compile" visibility="public" />
                <conf name="provided" visibility="public" />
                <conf name="runtime" visibility="public" extends="compile"/>
                <conf name="test" visibility="private extends="runtime"/>
                <conf name="system" visibility="public" />
                <conf name="sources" visibility="public"/>
                <conf name="javadoc" visibility="public" "/>
                <conf name="optional" visibility="public"/>
    </configurations> 

    <publications>
        <artifact conf="sources" ext="jar" type="source"/>
        <artifact conf="javadoc" ext="jar" type="javadoc"/>
        <artifact conf="default" ext="jar"/>
    </publications>

    <dependencies defaultconf="compile->default">
        <dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.5"/>

        <dependency org="zak-components" name="zak-components" rev="1.0"/>

        <dependency org="commons-collections" name="commons-collections" rev="3.2.1"/>

        <dependency org="net.sf.dozer" name="dozer" rev="3.4"/>

        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring" rev="2.0.2" transitive="false">
            <exclude module="jsf-api "/>
        </dependency>

        <dependency name="velocity" org="velocity" rev="1.4"/>

        <dependency name="mail" org="javax.mail" rev="1.4" conf="provided->default"/>

        <dependency org="org.mortbay.jetty" name="servlet-api-2.5" rev="6.1.14" conf="provided->default"/>

        <dependency org="org.acegisecurity" name="acegi-security" rev="1.0.1">
            <exclude org="org.springframework"/>
            <exclude org="tomcat"/>
        </dependency>

        <dependency org="dom4j" name="dom4j" rev="1.6.1"/>
        <dependency org="xalan" name="xalan" rev="2.5.1"/>
        <dependency org="log4j" name="log4j" rev="1.2.14"/>

        <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate" rev="3.2.6.ga">
            <exclude org="javax.transaction"/>
        </dependency>

        <dependency name="myfaces-api" org="org.apache.myfaces.core" rev="1.1.5">
            <exclude org="javax.mail"/>
            <exclude org="javax.resource"/>
        </dependency>


        <dependency org="commons-logging" name="commons-logging" rev="1.1.1"/>

        <exclude org="javax.ejb"/>
        <exclude org="javax.jms"/>
        <exclude org="com.bea"/>
        <exclude org="com.oracle"/>
        <exclude org="javax.activation"/>
        <exclude org="javax.ejb"/>
        <exclude module="commonj-twm"/>
        <exclude module="asm-util"/>
        <exclude module="commons-attributes-compiler"/>
        <exclude org="com.oracle"/>
        <exclude org="org.apache.geronimo.specs"/>
        <exclude org="openejb"/>
        <exclude org="javax.portlet"/>
        <exclude org="geronimo-spec"/>      
        <!-- exclude org=" javax.faces" module="jsf-api"/-->
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Comment: What is that `e:package` attribute? What namespace is `e`?

Comment: e uses the namesapce "http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra" to add extra attributes to ivy dependencies or the info element. Ivy should ignore them for dependency resolution. I use them to setup the eclipse classpath...

Comment: Shouldn't the file be called `ebusiness-core-1.0.xml`? The filename has to match the module and version, I think.

Comment: Yes, I just renamed it (the message displays module, group and version) to XYZ to make it shorter

Answer (score 0):

My stupidity. It was an old ivy.xml in a second repository ;-)